# Parse.com push-уведомления

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, разработка-игр, parse.com

Для андроид приложения (игры) необходимо разработать механизм push-уведомления.

Для разработки приложения использовался backend "Parse". В одной игре принимает участие два человека. Нужно чтобы, после ответа одного игрока, другому приходило уведомление о том, что вам ответили (или с вами хотят поиграть).

Подскажите как это примерно можно реализовать и куда заглянуть, кроме официальной документации Parse. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А сами как это сделали? свои труды можете коротко показать?

Comment: Я пока даже не знаю с чего начать. То есть, можно сделать уведомления который отправляются непосредственно с dashboard Parse. Но мне нужно, как я понимаю, чтобы одно устройство инициировало отправку уведомления, возможно с Parse. Как я понимаю, для этого нужно хранить device id пользователей.

Comment: Сейчас пока, вместо уведомления можно только ожидать ответа, то-есть приложение опрашивает базу до изменения в ней определенных полей.

Comment: а как на счет, держать соединение с сервером. Тоесть, соединение (Socket) не терять и если есть данные у сервера, отправляет данные через этот socket. Это типо WebSock

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю про WebSock. Просто я как таковое клиент - серверное соединение не использую, то есть есть Parse, который предоставляет мне свой api, я просто запрашиваю все в качестве клиента. И конечно хотелось бы сделать это средствами Parse

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно вам ничего знать про сокеты и проч. низкоуровневые штуки - все это делают библиотеки Parse.

Все что вам необходимо знать это идентификатор устройства куда вы посылаете пуш. Приемник может в принципе сообщить об этом через объект `ParseInstallation`

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("device_id", deviceToken); //номер устройства который дается при регистрации
installation.saveInBackground();
```

Тот кто посылает может сделать пуш фильтруя по этому идентификатору:

```
ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery(); 
query.whereEqualTo("device_id", deviceToken);    
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(query);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```

Можно поставить фильтр и по идентификатору юзера или названию канала.

Далее принимающая сторона должна "поднять" `BroadcastReceiver`, который и будет получать уведомление о полученном пуше соответствующим образом его обработать выставить нотификацию или popup box - в общем на ваше усмотрение.

Не хочется конечно советовать гуглить, но действительно погуглите. Зайдите на [гитхаб](https://github.com/) - там много лежит разных исходников/примеров.

Comment: То есть получается именно устройство инициирует отправку пуша сайтом Parse? Потому что, на сколько я понял в примере из документации уведомление отправляется именно с помощью сервера Parse.